# How can I read pdf document saved on my local drive? file or directory not found error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I tried multiple variations of the code below with no success (using , \, etc) in google-colab

```
file = r"C:\Users\walte\OneDrive\Documents\Nairobi.pdf"
table = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages=26)
table[0]
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\walte\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Nairobi.pdf.pdf'
```

Comment: Maybe the reader is adding .pdf to the end automatically. Make it `C:\Users\walte\OneDrive\Documents\Nairobi` and try.

Comment: have you tried ```\\``` or ```/``` while providing path

Answer (score 0):

The error says:
« FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\walte\OneDrive\Documents\Nairobi.pdf.pdf' »

Seems like tabula.read_pdf is automatically adding .pdf to the path.

I think «file = r"C:\Users\walte\OneDrive\Documents\Nairobi"» would be the solution.

Comment: I tried removing the .pdf extension.  I also tried using "\\" instead of "\". No success with either.   Any other ideas?

Comment: Read this section of the official tabula-py documentation: https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#get-tabula-py-working-windows-10

It says: If there’s a FileNotFoundError when it calls read_pdf(), and when you type java on command line it says 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, you should set PATH environment variable to point to the Java directory.